# Is chrome tabId unique across windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to know if the chrome tabId is unique across all the open windows. Incognito and normal. Is it guaranteed that non of the open tabs in all the windows will have the same tabId ?

I searched the documentation but could not find any reliable answer.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here, and say, considering you can drag a tab from window to window, that yes, it is unique.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, the tab ID is unique within a *browser session*. It's also mentioned in the documentation of [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab):

> `Tab
>
>   ( object )
>
>       id ( integer )
>
>          The ID of the tab. 
>   Tab IDs are unique within a browser session.`

If you still don't believe it, create an extension which has the `tabs` permission, and the right to run in an incognito window. Then run the following code in the background page:

```
// Create incognito window
chrome.windows.create({incognito: true, url:'about:blank'}, showTabId);
// Create normal window
chrome.windows.create({incognito: false, url:'about:blank'}, showTabId);

function showTabId(_window) {
    console.log(_window.tabs[0].id);        // Or alert, whatever.
    chrome.tabs.remove(_window.tabs[0].id); // Closes tab & window, user-friendly
}
```

The logged numbers are increasing (if you consider two numbers as a too small sample, run the [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) method in a loop, until you believe it).

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what is a session too ? Thus should there be conflicts with sync storage using tabId between navigator session ?

Comment: @Jean The session starts when you launch the browser for the first time, and ends when the main browser process exits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so two browsers on two different devices have different sessionId ? What about windowId and pageId ? I think there are distincts too, isn't it ?

Comment: "so two browsers on two different devices have different sessionId" - yes. "What about windowId" - this is only guaranteed to be unique within one session. "and pageId" - I guess you meant tabId; these are only unique within one session, similarly to windowId.

Comment: Wait so if I close a tab and then open some number of new tabs, those new tabs won't have the id the closed tab had?